# I want to build a voice recognition calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator, voice-recognition

i want to built voice recognition calculatos. my recognition event is working but i have a problem with evaluation. when i am trying to evaluate multiplication i am saying ,,five times three" and trancription gives me (5 X 3), then there is an error. eval() can not see X as multiplication.

also i cant use percentage or brackets with voice recognition. can someone help me with this?
`

```
    function speechRecognition() {
      const recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
      recognition.lang = "en-US";

      recognition.onstart = function () {
        microphone.classList.add(`listening`);
      };
      recognition.onspeechend = function () {
        microphone.classList.remove(`listening`);
        recognition.stop();
      };
      recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        const transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;

       let result = eval(transcript);
        displayOutput.innerHTML = cleanOutput(result);
      };

      recognition.start();
    }
```

Comment: So you will need to convert X to *. Should be a simple simple replace statement.

Comment: Use different keywords or pairs of then for parens?  "left" "right" or?  "five plus left two times seven right"